# Recursive print function from the friend ostream& operator<< function

Tags: c++

I need help writing a recursive print function from the `friend ostream& operator<<` function:

```
template <class Type>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Stack<Type>& list){
      //CODE GOES HERE
}
```

This is for a singly linked list that must print in reverse through recursion.

The linked list uses a template class and a struct Node:

```
    template<class Type>
    struct Node {
      Type data;
      Node *next;
    };
```

here are more instructions for this function:

> Outputs the items in the stack formated as item1->item2->...->itemn. For example, if the stack is 1,2,3,4 with the 4 on top of the stack, this method outputs 1->2->3->4. Note that this method prints in order from the bottom of the stack to the top of the stack. Use recursion to accomplish this. When implementing the stack it is recommended that you use the head of the list as the top of the stack. This makes the pop method more efficient.

The test files use the << operator to call get output, so my `std::ostream& operator<<` is where the code needs to come from. Additional private functions can be created and called from this function if needed.

I have already implemented all other functions Constructor, Destructor, Copy, Push, Pop, etc for this Stack Class.

I can get the two following functions to compile - but they don't pass the tests in the given cpp file.

```
template <class Type>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Stack<Type>& list){
    
     auto current = list.getHead();
    
    list.reversePrint(current, out);
    
    return out;
}

void Stack<Type>::reversePrint(const Node<Type>* curr, std::ostream& out) const {
    
    if (curr == nullptr) {
        return;
    }       

    // print the list after head node
    reversePrint(curr->next, out);

    // After everything else is printed, print head
    cout << curr->data << "->";     
}

The cpp file for testing this section is:
bool testOutput(){
   bool passed = true;
   cout << "-------------Test Output--------------" << endl;
   Stack<int> intStack;
   ostringstream output;
   output << intStack;
   passed &= checkTest("Output 1", output.str(), string(""));
   output.str("");
   output.clear();
   intStack.push(4);
   output << intStack;
   passed &= checkTest("Output 2", output.str(), string("4"));
   output.str("");
   output.clear();
   intStack.push(8);
   output << intStack;
   passed &= checkTest("Output 3", output.str(), string("4->8"));
   output.str("");
   output.clear();
   intStack.push(1);
   output << intStack;
   passed &= checkTest("Output 4", output.str(), string("4->8->1"));

the output using the test code says:


-------------Test Output--------------
Passed Output 1
4->***Failed test Output 2 **
   Output was
   Output should have been 4
4->8->***Failed test Output 3 **
   Output was
   Output should have been 4->8
4->8->1->***Failed test Output 4 **
   Output was
   Output should have been 4->8->1
4->8->1->5->
```

from running the debugger, this seems to tell me that the output needs to come through the friend ostream& operator<< function when it is returned instead of a helper function.  I am wondering if the helper function returned the coded information and the output comes from the ostream& operator function, if that would work, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: As is, it wouldn't do you any good even if you could. The member function prints to `std::cout`, but the operator takes the output stream as an argument. Your member needs to do the same.

Comment: Thank you for your response -WhozCraig.  I have updated my question so it is more clear.

Comment: Your output always ends with trailing `->`, that's what makes the tests fail. The general structure of the code is correct, you just need to figure out a way to print one fewer `->` than numbers.